# running maven jetty causing a dependency error

Tags: java, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I've this wired java compilation error when I start jetty. I'm running naven build and it gives me success, however when i run the mvn jetty:run command, it gives the following error:

```
EXCEPTION org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP||PWC6199: Generated servlet error:|org.apache.jsp.tag.web.ui.static_tag is not abstract and does not override abstract method getDependants() in org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent||PWC6199: Generated servlet error:|getDependants() in org.apache.jsp.tag.web.ui.static_tag cannot implement getDependants() in org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent|  return type java.util.List<java.lang.String> is not compatible with java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>||
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
```

I'm using the maven-jetty-plugin for running jetty.
I've tried re-installing the environment that I'm currently working, and also checkout my project ina different directory. Nothing has worked so far. Does have nay ideas what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem would be one of the followings:

- You have a dependency to glassfish in your pom.xml: This was the problem in my case
- You are using a different version of servlet-api than your jetty uses. To solve this you can add provided tag to your servlet-api dependency that makes the jetty to use its own servlet version:

  javax.servlet
  servlet-api
  3.2
  provided

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Jetty plugin helped me

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html
this link points to the root cause of the problem
https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/201784186-Error-in-Javac-compilation-for-JSP-in-LucidWorks-Search-UI

FYI my plugin configuration

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```